# Preprocessing directive from a vendor defined using brackets rather than quotes

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, brackets, preprocessor-directive

I am looking at some **C** code from a vendor with pre-compiled **C** files with header files of their own. The problem I'm having is this: Since it is vendor specific code, I don't have read/write access to the code (it is stopping me for some reason, but that's a different issue) and they defined their preprocessing directives as:

```
#include <fun.h>
```

which is fine, but since I can't edit the file, I cannot append the path of the .h file, as

```
#include "C:\some\directory\fun.h"
```

I'm assuming when I installed their software on my computer the install did not put everything where it was supposed to go, because it says it does so in the documentation, and it is a new version of their software, so.. yeah, bugs.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to include the path without moving the entire contents to a local directory, or the system directory, of which I'm not even sure what those directories are, but I know there are a few.

Solution:
Add the folder to the path directory by adding the path to

Project Name -> Search Directories ->  Compiler (This one is specifically in code blocks)
This is also assuming you are using an IDE. If compiling from the cmd prompt, the solution I've check marked is the correct one.

If the file you are trying to compile is not part of the project, it will repeatedly ask you to build the file, and then do nothing. So make sure to add it to the project.

In addition.
The issue I was having, namely, being unable to edit the vendor files, was actually due 
to read only permissions for the folder Program Files (x86). There are probably several workarounds, Simply changing the permissions to read/write is not enough. As I understand it, I was working on a windows 7 platform, and this is a feature of windows 7. I found it easier to just move the file I wanted to edit to another folder, change the code, and then move it back.

Comment: for 'gcc' use '-IpathToIncludeFiles' near the end of the line that compiles the files. I.E after any file names.  If your performing both compile and link in one step, put the above parameter before any '-LpathToLibrary' and '-llibraryName' parameters

Comment: the only difference between #include <...> and #include "..." is in what order the directorys are searched for the include files.  the <...> searches in the system directories first.  the "..." searches in the user directories first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `C:\some\directory` to the include search path. 
most compilers do this with a `-I` or `/I` switch

for `gcc` add `-I C:/some/directory` to the compiler command line